# How to await (DataBase change); in Web API Controller C#

Tags: c#, .net, controller, webapi

I have some Web API controllers programmed for serving an mobile application.

In one of the controllers I insert some data in the database (with status 0), then I need to wait for other external call to change the status and when is changed (or 10 seconds have passed) return a JSON.

So resuming: I need to wait for a column on a table (with unique ID) to change before my Web API controller continues... If the column don't change in 10 seconds then it will return an error....

I was trying to use `SqlDependency` but I can't get it to wait until is changed, I don't want to trigger something after is changed, I need to know if it has changed while waiting...

I need something like this:

```
int RequestStatus = await CheckRequestStatusChangeOnDB(RequestID,10);
//await until database change or until 10 seconds has passed...
if (RequestStatus == 1)
                {//do something}
if (RequestStatus == 2)
                {//do something}
if (RequestStatus == 0)
                {//no change in database}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WhenAny` to create a `Task` that will be completed when one of a number of tasks has completed, in combination with `Task.Delay` to create a task that will be completed in 10 seconds.  Once `WhenAny` completes you can then check if your `Task` has completed, and if so, what the result is.

Comment: Thanks @servy ... This will solve handling both conditions.... But what about checking the change on the database... How can I handle that??... How could I code the CheckRequestStatusChangeOnDB? Thanks!!

Comment: @ricardo_escovar That's an entirely different question from what you asked.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain me well @servy and sorry for that... There are really two quesrions in one... The first one (about two conditions task) that you already answered and I appreciate that... And the second one to wait for a database change to give a result (that's why I have it on the title and commented about SqlDependency) .. Can you help me with that? Thanks

Comment: Any one with any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You want recursive method running with statuses but when break?
For this example im  marking 10 as break value.

```
public async bool CheckRequestStatus(int requestId, StatusEnum lastStatus)
{
    int requestStatus = await GetRequestStatusById(requestId);
    if (requestStatus == lastStatus)
    {
        Task.Delay(10);
        CheckRequestStatus(requestId, requestStatus);
    }        

    switch(Enum.Parse<StatusEnum>(requestId))
        case Processing:
            DoProcess();
            CheckRequestStatus(requestId, Processing);
            break;
        case Finishing:
            DoFinishing();
            CheckRequestStatus(requestId, Finishing);
            break;
        case End:
            DoEnd();
            break;
        default:
            break;

    return true;
}

public enum StatusEnum{
    Processing = 1,
    Finishing = 2,
    End = 10
}
```